# Use cells in Active Sheet to Populate Links to External Cell References

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Concerning external references, I have entered

```
='Drive:\path\[workbook_name.xlsx]Sheet_Name!cell_name
```

and this is working as an alternative to the INDIRECT function, as I am working with closed workbooks, but now I have the question: how do I ask Excel to pull the data from cells in the active sheet for use in this formula? For instance

```
='Drive:\path\Sales\Cashier Return Sheets\FY2017(use value from cell) [(use value from cell).xlsx]Thursday 1'!$C$40?
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it helps.

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-external-reference-link-to-a-cell-range-in-another-workbook-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f

have a good day